# $A$ is diagonalizable $\iff A^{-1}$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I used that proposition while doing an exercise and later realized it hadn't been demonstrated in class so i proceeded trying to prove it myself as it follows: Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb{K})$ be invertible, than exists $A^{-1}\in M_n(\Bbb{K})$; Let then  V be a vector space and $L_A=:f\in End(V)$. Now if $A$ is diagonalizable there exist a base $\mathscr{B}=\left( v_1,\dots,v_n \right)$ for V such that $$M_{\mathscr{B}}\left(f\right)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \lambda_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now since $f\circ f^{-1}=Id_V$, it must be true that $M_{\mathscr{B}}\left(f\right) \cdot M_{\mathscr{B}}\left(f^{-1}\right)=Id_n$; therefore
$$ M_{\mathscr{B}}\left(f^{-1}\right)=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\over\lambda_1 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 1\over\lambda_2 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1\over\lambda_n \\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
and so we found that $A$ being diagonalizable implies $A^{-1}$ is diagonalizable. Now, since the inverse of $A^{-1}$ is actually $A$, for the same argument we can conclude that $A^{-1}$ being diagonalizable implies $A$ is diagonalizable and therefore the thesis. Is my argument correct? Could I prove it quicker? Because I believe my proof is correct as much as I believe it could be done in a smarter way.

Comment: "Let ∈() be invertible" @2nd row assures me that, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is correct. A quicker way could be the following:
$A$ is diagonalizable $\iff$ $D=BAB^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal (and invertible since so is $A$) and $B$ invertible $\iff$ $BA^{-1}B^{-1}=(BAB^{-1})^{-1}=(D)^{-1}=D^{-1}$ $\iff$ $A^{-1}$ is diagonalizable ($D^{-1}$ is clearly diagonal as is the inverse of a diagonal matrix).

Comment: yep, clearly quicker; thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome! If you're satisfied with the answer please accept it by clicking on the check-mark on the left of the answer

Comment: @MatteoIaccarino Another user could still come and post an answer which is better than yours. You should therefore not pressure the author to "accept" your answer a few minutes after the question was posted. Indeed this could lead to OP to leave the website and miss out on better answers. If you feel like the author genuinely forgot to accept an answer then you can politely remind them later.

Comment: There is no better answer :D